# Uploading Magento Enterprise and Community Extensions

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-community, magento-connect

So for about 2 years we have had a single version of our extension to cater for both Enterprise and Community however we plan to launch a separate version today for Enterprise with some exclusive functionality.

So I now have 2 packages to upload to Magento connect, I've already uploaded the community version with only community versions supported selected however the Enterprise version now wont upload as the version number already exists.

All I'm looking to achieve is a user can select on Magento connect whether they want the Community or Enterprise version and the correct package to download.

My initial thought is you need to run the 2 packages on different version numbers but that seems a little silly, but could anyone confirm this is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to offer exclusive functionality for one of both, you should provide an additional module which extends yours.
Or if it is a free module, simply put some switches inside your module so it is only active for enterprise.